# CSS validation in Visual Studio: ignore file

Tags: css, visual-studio, validation

In my ASP.NET Core project I have a third party CSS file which causes Visual Studio 2022 to show many warnings. How can I tell VS to ignore this file for CSS validation?

I am aware that I could disable CSS validation altogether (Options->Text Editor->CSS-Advanced->Enable validation: False), but that is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. After asking ChatGPT (GPT-4) the answer is clear: No there is no direct solution at the moment:

> Unfortunately, there isn't a built-in way to disable CSS validation
> for specific files in Visual Studio 2022 without disabling it
> globally.
>
> However, you can try the following workaround that might help you to
> suppress the warnings:
>
> Locate the third-party CSS file in the Solution Explorer. Right-click
> on the file and select "Properties." In the "Properties" window, set
> the "Build Action" to "None." This will prevent the file from being
> built and should suppress the warnings. However, this workaround may
> also prevent the file from being copied to the output folder during
> the build process. So, you may need to manually copy the third-party
> CSS file to the appropriate output folder.
>
> Also, please make sure to include the file in your _Layout.cshtml or
> index.html (for Blazor WebAssembly) with the correct path, so it is
> loaded when the application runs.
>
> Unfortunately, there is no direct solution to exclude specific CSS
> files from validation in ASP.NET Core projects using Visual Studio
> 2022. The CSS validation feature currently lacks the ability to target specific files for exclusion.
>
> As mentioned earlier, you can disable CSS validation globally, but it
> is not an ideal solution since it will disable validation for all CSS
> files in your project.
>
> Another alternative is to use a Visual Studio extension like Web
> Essentials or Web Compiler, which might provide better control over
> the validation process. However, these extensions may not provide a
> direct way to exclude specific files from validation either.
>
> In summary, there is no direct and perfect solution to exclude
> specific CSS files from validation in ASP.NET Core projects using
> Visual Studio 2022. You may consider using the workarounds mentioned
> earlier or exploring third-party extensions that might help you
> control the validation process better.

---

So why not put the third party css file outside the project and include it in the build process (e.g. a MSBuild Copy command) if possible. Therefore you should not see the error.

I disabled CSS validation globally for myself, since I do not need it.